# Play and Pause .GIF animations in winform

Tags: c#, .net

I chose a GIF image for somethings like "Button Control"(Not PictureBox) and it can play .GIF images.

```
private void radApplicationMenu1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    ImageAnimator.StopAnimate(radApplicationMenu1.Image, null); // <-- returns null!
    radApplicationMenu1.DropDownButtonElement.ShowDropDown(); 
}
```

Now, I want the image would be played or paused is using different mouse events(e.g. leave or mouse hover) till the moment that fire event of mouse hover fixed and immediately after receiving an event will be played (e.g. after four seconds).
Again, stay pause till the next mouse and will be played to the end and stay paused after that. In other words, event and plays of images happen simultaneously by the events.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with:

```
// start
System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.Animate(yourImage, OnFrameChanged);

// stop
System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.StopAnimate(yourImage, OnFrameChanged);

private void OnFrameChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
}
```

## Edit

You could also show this Image inside a PictureBox and if you want the .gif to stop, just call **pictureBox.Enabled = false**

## Edit 2

```
private void radApplicationMenu1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    // This stops the animation
    ImageAnimator.StopAnimate(radApplicationMenu1.Image, null);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: This is the Eventhandler. If I am not wrong you could also do something like **System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.StopAnimate(yourImage, null);** If you don't want to handle if the image of that .gif has changed

Comment: My control doesn't have on frame changed event.

Comment: No, you don't need to create the method, just put **null** into there

Comment: No, This method does not stop the photo

Comment: Actually I cannot test it by myself yet, but what if you call **ImageAnimator.StopImage** from a Button Click? Does this neither stop the Image? And have you tried yourPictureBox.Enabled?

Comment: I do not want to use Picturebox.

Comment: I think I misunderstand you. So you've got a Button where it's background Image is a .gif?

Comment: Nooo, i added a .gif image to the button and back color of this button is white